# Two linked NSTables by NSArrayControllers are not updating simultaneously, if I update one of them

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I am using Core data in cocoa. Since I cannot post pictures, I will try my best to explain the problem
My object model is:
**Book:highlightInBooks >> Highlight**

Objects are managed by BookArrayController and HighlightArrayController.
BookNSTableView datasource is BookArrayController and HighlightNSTableView datasource is HighlightArrayController.

I have created a NSMenu for highlight table that use **Highlight attribute: markHighlightToTrash**
The action attached to NSMenue item:

```
- (IBAction)trashHighlight:(id)sender {
Highlight *highlight = [_highlightArrayController arrangedObjects][[_highlightTableView clickedRow]];
    [highlight setHighlightToTrash];
]
```

In highlight subclass:

```
-(void) setHighlightToTrash{
    self.markHighlightToTrash = @1;
}
```

So what above code does is, when user trash all the highlight of a book in Highlight table trash that book in Book Table also.

I have set two NSButton in the sidebar namely AllBooks and Trash.

```
- (IBAction)allBookButton:(id)sender {

    NSPredicate *predicateTwo = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(highlightsInBook, $highlight, $highlight.markHighlightToTrash = NO) .@count > 0"];
    [_bookArrayController setFilterPredicate:predicateTwo];

    [_highlightArrayController setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markHighlightToTrash = NO "]];   
}

- (IBAction)trashButton:(id)sender {

    [_highlightArrayController setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markHighlightToTrash = YES"]];

    NSPredicate *predicateTwo = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(highlightsInBook, $highlight, $highlight.markHighlightToTrash = YES) .@count > 0"];
    [_bookArrayController setFilterPredicate:predicateTwo];
}
```

So if AllBooks is clicked, tables will show only those books which are not marked to trash. And when Trash button is clicked tables will show books whose highlight is marked as trash.

**Problem** While above code works, the problem is when I mark all the highlight of Book X in highlight table, the Book X still remain visible in BookTable.
*Although when I click Trash button and agin click back AllBook button, the Book X, do hide (as intended).*

So why Book table only updates itself after I cycle through those two buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arraycontrollers don't (and can't) observe the properties used in the filter predicate. If you want to reapply the filter after changing highlight, you can do so with `[arrayController rearrangeObjects]`.